# Disable logging for specific controller actions in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller

I've found numerous examples for doing this with Rails 2.*, but none of them have worked with my Rails 3.1 setup.

Does anyone know how to completely disable logging for specific controller actions?

Comment: how did you do this in Rails 2.3?

Comment: I'd really, really like to see an example, or reference, to fix an app I'm maintaining.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap action in log silencer via around filter

```
around_filter :silence_action, :only => :action

def silence_action
  Rails.logger.silence do
    yield
  end
end
```

Comment: No luck with this either. Logging must take place before filters even run?

Comment: Hmm. This means that you need silence logger before Rails::Rack::Logger middleware.. But it's running before rails routing, so you can't bind action.. Maybe there is another way to 'reset' current log..